# How to implement interface having a signature of interface type with generic class

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I am having problem implementing an interface with signature having interface.

```
public interface IReport
{
    IReportOutput Execute(IReportInput input); 
}

public class ReportBase<TInput, TOutput> : IReport where TInput : IReportInput, new() where TOutput : IReportOutput, new()
{

    public TOutput Execute(TInput input)
    {

    }
}
```

This is giving me compile time error the interface is not implemented, can it be done or not, I just want to implement an interface method with different input and output classes.

Comment: the method signature in the interface expects an object of type `IReportInput` but the concrete implementation uses a `TInput`. The 2 signatures don't match, hence the error.

Comment: `IReport abc = <some ReportBase instance>; abc.Execute(<some other implementation of IReportInput>);` see the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a public method to implement (implicitly) an interface method, it must have the same signature. One quick and dirty way to work around that is to provide an explicit implementation which delegates its work:

```
IReportOutput IReport.Execute(IReportInput input) => Execute((TInput)input);
```

Note the cast: your `ReportBase` class can be cast to `IReport` and be used with a parameter which is *not* of type `TInput` - you'll get an invalid cast exception if you try to do so.

A safer approach is to use variance:

```
public interface IReport<in TInput, out TOutput>
    where TInput : IReportInput
    where TOutput : IReportOutput
{
    TOutput Execute(TInput input);
}

public class ReportBase<TInput, TOutput> : IReport<TInput, TOutput>
    where TInput : IReportInput, new()
    where TOutput : IReportOutput, new()
{
    public TOutput Execute(TInput input)
    {
        return default(TOutput);
    }
}
```

Here, `IReport` is *contravariant* on `TInput` and *covariant* on `TOutput`.

Comment: I tried this way but when finally I need to cast my report to IReport<T1,T2> it gives me invalid cast exception my class declaration is like TestReport:ReportBase<TestInput,TestOutput> I have to cast TestReport to IReport to call report.Execute(input)

Answer (score 0):

You could use generics

```
public interface IReport<InputType, OutputType>
{
    OutputType Excecute(InputType input);
}
```

then implement the interface as

```
public class ReportBase : IReport<TInput, TOutput>
{
    public TOutput Execute(TInput input)
    {
        // Implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: I initially used generic interface but when I Cast ReportBase to IReport<IReportInput,IReportOutput> it gives invalid cast exception

Comment: @kami998 see the answer above. It's probably the best solution.